# webshere mq .net client event based listen

Tags: ibm-mq

Is it possible to event driven listen in websheremq.I mean when a message writing to queue ,should I pull everytime do you have message or event driven listen possible.

```
while(true)
{//each time I check queue has a message
queueu.Get(....)
}
```

or

```
queue.Listen()=>run my codes ?something like that delegate logic?
```

What I have to do listen queue strategy?

Comment: You can do "Get with Wait" or use .NET MQ XMS as it has a callback method see https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/messaging/entry/message_listeners_in_xms_net?lang=en

Comment: .xms I try to use this one without installing mq client ,is it possible do that without installing client?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the .net API of MQ, but an async get feature is implemented on the MQI API. You need the MQCB and MQCTL calls.

There is a sample program provided by IBM called amqscbf written in C.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q023050_.htm

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q024020_.htm